# Tridiagonal matrix with corners with a lot of symmetry

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

I really want to find the eigenvalues of this matrix:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
a_{0} & 1 & 0 &  & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & a_{1} & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & a_{2} &  & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 & \vdots &  & \ddots &  & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 &  & a_{L-3} & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & a_{L-2} & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 &  & 0 & 1 & a_{L-1}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where
$$a_{n}=2\cos\left(2\pi\frac{n}{L}\right).$$
Note that $a_{n+L}=a_n$.

I've done quite a bit of research on the internet about tridiagonal matrices but I cannot find any source of information suitable to my problem. I don't even know if these specific matrices have a name.

Usually I'd accept that this is as hard a problem as finding the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix with any old $a_n$. However, this has so much symmetry that it makes me wonder if there's a way. If there is such a way, maybe I could use it to solve other problems that arise in a similar context.

If you're interested about the context, I'm studying the Landau levels of a simple tight-binding Hamiltonian on a square lattice with nearest neighbor interactions, periodic boundary conditions and a constant magnetic field using the Landau Gauge.

Comment: Does anything interesting or inspiring happen for small $n$, say $2,3$? I don't know enough about your problem to have an intuition, so I would just expect this to be hard. But I'm not an expert at all. Maybe someone here will have an idea!

Comment: If all else fails, you can use a software for that. Matlab, or there are linalg modules in python, also maybe https://www.wolframalpha.com/ knows.  The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, which is the determinant of  an alike tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In reality, all I need is the numeric value of these eigenvalues, and as a matter of fact I have used Mathematica to obtain them. But I cannot help but wonder if there's an elegant solution to this problem. Regarding @AlfredYerger's comment, for small $n$, some interesting eigenvalues appear.
 $n=4$: {$-\sqrt8$, $-\sqrt8$, 0, 0}, 
$n=8$: {-$\sqrt(2 (4 + \sqrt2))$, $\sqrt(2 (4 + \sqrt2))$, -2, 2, -$\sqrt(2 (2 - \sqrt2))$, $-\sqrt(2 (2 - \sqrt2))$, 0, 0}. You may check that these are some known values for trigonometric functions